# How to get dynamic page content with capybara

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, capybara, poltergeist

Trying to get text from elements:

```
<div class="points-text" data-reactid=".2765swfgy68.1.2.2.1:$sony-xperia-z1-compact.2.0.4.0.0.1">29,367 points</div>
```

I guess websites uses Reactjs and capybara can't get content even with Poltergeist driver. Is there any workaround?

Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'


Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {js_errors: false})
end


class WebScraper
  include Capybara::DSL

  def get_page_data(url)
    visit(url)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.html)
    p doc.css('.points-text')
  end
end


scraper = WebScraper.new
puts scraper.get_page_data('http://versus.com/en/sony-xperia-z1-compact')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to parse the html with Nokogiri if you're already visiting with Capybara.

```
def get_page_data(url)
  visit(url)
  p find(:css, '.points-text').text      
end
```

will print the visible text in the element with class points-text

Comment: @ambi worked for me. I guess you're probably using phantomjs < 2 which doesn't provide bind so react fails, you'd see that if you didn't have js_errors: false

Answer (score 0):

This code works with **selenium** and **webkit** but it does NOT work with **poltergeist** driver.
From the screenshots i can see that javascript on the website is not even executed.

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara-webkit'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
# Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
# Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {js_errors: false})
end
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.allow_unknown_urls
end


class WebScraper
  include Capybara::DSL

  def get_page_data(url)
    visit(url)

    max_same_times = 3
    same_times = 0
    old_points = nil
    20.times do |i|
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.html)
      # p doc.css('.points-text')
      points = doc.css('.points-text')
      # p [same_times, max_same_times]
      if same_times == max_same_times
        break
      end
      if points.length > 0
        points = points[0].text
        # p [old_points, points]
        if old_points == points
          same_times += 1
        else
          same_times = 0
        end
        old_points = points
      end
      page.save_screenshot("#{i}.png")
    end
    old_points
  end
end


scraper = WebScraper.new
puts scraper.get_page_data('http://versus.com/en/sony-xperia-z1-compact')
```

Comment: I don't understand why you keep wanting to use Nokogiri when you're already using Capybara - it's just wasted html parsing.  You can just do  points = all(:css, '.points-text') to return an array like object of all the matching elements on the page rather than continuously reparsing the page html using Nokogiri.  You could also use points = all(:css, '.points-text', minimum: 1) if you want it to wait forl at least one element to show and then return all matching, or just first(:css, 'points-text', minimum: 1) to get the first matching element on the page since thats all your code seems to use